# When will my google play update appear to users?

Tags: android, google-play, publish, mobile-application

I sent an update to the application I developed 1 month ago on Google Play. Accepted

The update date on the Google Play Store link has also changed.

But there is no button for users to install the new update-style application.

Is the only solution to wait? guess how long to wait

Answer (score 1):

Google says the review process could take up to 7 days or even longer. But usually it takes up to 2 days. also please try to check Any notification or email on your account for any restriction or violation against Google play.